# Angular + core How to upload Array of file from Angular to Dot Net Core

Tags: angular, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-2.0

Here is fetching an Array of File for uploading. but I'm not able to bind my Data

```
fileList: File[] = [];
listOfFiles: any[] = [];
 onFileChanged(event: any) {
    for (var i = 0; i <= event.target.files.length - 1; i++) {
      var selectedFile = event.target.files[i];
      this.fileList.push(selectedFile);
      this.listOfFiles.push(selectedFile.name)
  }
}
```

Here im Uploding my file to Server

```
upload() {
  const formData: any = new FormData();
formData.append('ofile',this.fileList)
  console.log('form data variable :   '+ formData.toString());
this._service.PostFormData(formData).subscribe(data=>{  
});
}
```

**HTML code**

```
<input type="file" (change)="onFileChanged($event)">
<input type="file" (change)="onFileChanged($event)">
<input type="file" (change)="onFileChanged($event)">

<!-- <button mat-icon-button (click)="removeSelectedFile(index)">delete</button> -->
<button (click)="upload()">Save</button>
```

core side I'm using

```
    public class Test
    {
      //  public List<IFormFile> ofile { get; set; }
        public byte[] ofile { get; set; }
  }
```

**COntroller**

```
[HttpPost]
    public IActionResult GetName([FromForm]Test oTest)
    {
      }
```

Here I'm getting Null Value Please Helpme How Can I Overcome This issue

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should foreach the fileList and add the file to formData one by one.

```
upload() {
const formData: any = new FormData();
$.each(this.fileList, function (i, file) {
    formData.append('ofile', file);
});
this._service.PostFormData(formData).subscribe(data=>{  
});
}
```

Model:

```
public class Test
{
    public List<IFormFile> ofile { get; set; }
}
```